# What is the relation between chemical potential and the number of particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

Chemical potential is defined as the change in energy due to change in the number of particles in a system. Let we have a system which is defined by the following Hamiltonian:
$$H = -t \sum_i^L c_i^\dagger c_{i+1} + V\sum_i^L n_i n_{i+1} -\mu \sum_i^L n_i$$
where $c^\dagger (c)$ are creation (annihilation) operators, $n$ is number operator, $t$ is hopping parameter, $V$ is nearest-neighbor interaction, $L$ is the total number of sites and $\mu$ is chemical potential.

What I understand by chemical potential is, if we set $μ=$some constant, then no matter how many sites ($L$) we add to the system, the number of particles will always be conserved. (Please correct me if I am wrong)

**QUESTION:**

What is the relation between chemical potential and the number of particles? i.e. if I set $μ = 10$ then how many particles are allowed in the system?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_potential#Thermodynamic_definition and possible duplicate https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/92314/meaning-of-the-chemical-potential-for-a-boson-gas

Comment: Thermodynamically, $\mu = \partial G / \partial N$ and is the free energy cost of adding another particle. Of you "fix" $\mu$, that says nothing about $N$.

Comment: For an ideal gas of bosons or fermions, the chemical potential determines the mean number of bosons (fermions) at the ground state   $N_0=\frac{1}{\exp(-\mu/kT)\mp 1} $ (the minus sign refers to bosons, plus - to fermions . If the particle density is also specified, the chemical potential determines the mean value of the total number of particles $N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At zero temperature, to find the relation between $\mu$ and the  particle number you have to know the ground-state energy $E_N$  of the system with $N$ particles, and then $\mu= E_{N+1}-E_N$ Consequently you have to solve your Hubbard model exactly before anything else.

Once  you have done this, you can  approximate the definition of $\mu$  as 
$$
\mu = \frac{\partial E}{\partial N}
$$
(where $E=E(N)=E_N$) and from this  obtain $N$ as a function of $\mu$ by means of Legendre transformation. Set
$$
\Phi= E-\mu N
$$
Then
$$
\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \mu} = \frac{\partial E}{\partial\mu} -N-\mu \frac{\partial N}{\partial \mu}
$$
$$
=\frac{\partial E}{\partial N}\frac{\partial N}{\partial\mu }  - N- \frac{\partial E}{\partial N}\frac {\partial N}{\partial \mu}
$$ 
$$
= -N
$$

At finite temperature  a thermodynamic system with a fixed chemical potential must be in a grand canonical ensemble and therefore  free to exchange particles with a reservoir. Consequently  the particle number is *not* fixed but  instead its *average* $<N>$ is  determined by 
$$
<N> = - \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \mu}
$$
where now 
$$
\Phi \to E-TS-\mu N 
$$
is the thermodynamic grand potential.

Comment: Thank you. I need $T=0$. Just another quick question, does $\mu$ remain same for all particles? i.e. if $E_2 -E_1 = a$, will $E_{10}-E_9=a$?

Comment: @Sana Ullah. No.  $E_{N+1}-E_N$ will depend on $N$, that is why I said you had to solve your Hubbard model first (and good luck with that! -- it is a famously hard problem!)

Comment: wow. actually i wanted to fix the chemical potential such that number of particles always remain half of number of sites, for exact diagonalization of the Hubbard model. I need results for only 10 sites. You might want to have a look at my so far progress: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/459178/numerical-exact-diagonalization-of-tight-binding-hamiltonian . thank you for your time, Sir.