# Numerical exact diagonalization of tight binding Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, computational-physics, eigenvalue

I want to exactly diagonalize the following Hamiltonian for $10$ number of sites and $4$ number of spinless fermions
$$H = -t\sum_i^{L-1} \big[c_i^\dagger c_{i+1} - c_i c_{i+1}^\dagger\big] + V\sum_i^{L-1} n_i n_{i+1}$$
here $L$ is total number of sites, creation ($c^\dagger$) and annihilation ($c$) operators are defined as following
$$
c = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0\\1&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and $n_i = c_i^\dagger c_i$ is number operator.

To exactly diagonalize (for simplicity let's take $L=4$ sites), one can expand $H$ as

$$H = -t\big[
c_1^\dagger \sigma_1^z \otimes c_2\otimes I_3 \otimes I_4 \\
+ I_1 \otimes c_2^\dagger \sigma_2^z \otimes c_3\otimes I_4\\
+ I_1 \otimes I_2 \otimes c_3^\dagger\sigma_3^z \otimes c_4
\big]+h.c.\\
+V\big[
n_1 \otimes n_2 \otimes I_3 \otimes I_4\\
+I_1 \otimes n_2 \otimes n_3 \otimes I_4\\
+I_1 \otimes I_2 \otimes n_3 \otimes n_4 
\big]$$
where $\sigma^z$ (Pauli matrix) is just simple matrix multiplication for the sake of anti-commutation relation.

So far so good. (please correct me if I am doing anything wrong)!

**Question:**

I used the above method and numerically calculated the ground state and found that above method gives correct results for $V=0$ but when $V\ne0$ the results are wrong.

Eventually, I get to the point that I am not taking care of number of particles in the system. How do we numerically diagonalize a Hamiltonian matrix in the sector with chosen number of particles?

Comment: Can you show that $c_1^\dagger$ and $c_2$ anti-commute? If I follow your recipe and try to calculate the anticommutator of $c_1^\dagger = c^\dagger\sigma^z \otimes I$ and $c_2 = I \otimes \sigma^z c$ then I do not get the null matrix.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to numerically diagonalize a Hamiltonian, it is recommended to construct nonzero elements $H_{ij} = \langle i|H|j\rangle$ instead of using the Kronecker product $\otimes$. You can follow this algorithm:

1. Build the Wannier basis.
2. Apply the Hamiltonian to each basis state.
3. Utilize algebra software to solve the eigenvalue problem.

---

Here's an example for a system with $L = 4$ sites and $N = 2$ particles:

1. Generate the basis, which consists of all possible states for $L$ sites with $N$ particles: ${0: |0011\rangle, 1: |0101\rangle, 2: |1010\rangle, 3: |1100\rangle, 4: |1001\rangle, 5: |0110\rangle}$.
   To generate and enumerate combinations, you can use [combinadics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system).
2. Apply the Hamiltonian:

   - The interaction term $n_i n_j$ produces diagonal elements, for example: $H_{0,0} = \langle 0011|H|0011 \rangle = V$.
   - The hopping term $c_i^\dagger c_{i+1}$ produces off-diagonal elements, for example: $H_{5,2} = \langle0110|H|1010\rangle = -t$ (Note: Fermions anticommute, so in the hopping term, one should consider fermion operator permutations. If required, multiply this term by $-1$).
3. Use appropriate software like Matlab, [Armadillo](https://arma.sourceforge.net/) (C++), or [numpy](https://numpy.org/) (Python) to solve the eigenvalue problem for $H_{ij}$.