# Use of a geometric series sum in derivation of Bose-Einstein distribution

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, partition-function, bosons, chemical-potential

In the following Wiki [derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_statistics#Derivation_from_the_grand_canonical_ensemble) of the Bose-Einstein distribution, a geometric sum is used to make the following step

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left  (\exp \left (\frac{\mu -\epsilon}{k_B T}\right)\right)^n = \frac{1}{1-\exp\left(\frac{\mu -\epsilon}{k_B T}\right)}
$$

but using a geometric series [requires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) the absolute value of the argument to be less than 1.

Can I have some assistance in understanding why

$$
\exp \left(\frac{\mu -\epsilon}{k_B T}\right )
$$

is necessarily less than 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chemical potential of a Boson gas is always negative or (at worst) zero. (See [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/92314/157014) for why.)

Since the system is considered to be non-interacting (ideal), the Hamiltonian is just the kinetic energy. The lowest energy is thus the $\epsilon_0=0$ state. This means that in general $\epsilon\geq0$, and so $$\exp{\left(\frac{\mu-\epsilon}{k_B T}\right)}\leq\exp{\left(-\frac{\epsilon}{k_B T}\right)}\leq1.$$

(The only case when the sum diverges is when this term is equal to 1, and when this happens the occupation of the lowest energy level diverges, which is in fact what happens in Bose-Einstein condensation.)

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! :D