# What does negative $\mu$ physically means?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, chemical-potential

I have recently heard the following statement:

> A negative chemical potential means absence of particles.

However, I cannot make this consistent with e.g. a system of free bosons for which $\mu$ must be negative to ensure stability of the partition function.

Comment: Source for this quote? Related to your question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/92314/

Comment: See e.g. here http://qpt.physics.harvard.edu/c58.pdf at the end of pag 5.

How should I then interpret "The ground state for μ < 0 is the vacuum with no particles"?

Comment: The quote "A negative chemical potential means absence of particles." is in section 2.1 of your cited notes. Section 2 is about *fermions*, so the necessity of negative $\mu$ for bosons is irrelevent.

Answer (score 1):

Let me recapitulate to answer my own question

1. A system of boson requires $\mu\leq 0$ to ensure stability of the theory.
2. $\mu\leq 0$ means that the system is happy to accept new particles [Ref](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/92314/meaning-of-the-chemical-potential-for-a-boson-gas). This is sort of intuitive for a system of bosons
3. At $T=0$ the Bose distribution function vanishes. This means that
   \begin{equation}
   \mu\leq0 \rightarrow n_\text{B}(T=0,\epsilon)=0
   \end{equation}
   which ultimately means absence of particles.